# How to disable signature collection?

Tags: branch.io

Is there a way to disable collecting user signature when a deep-link is clicked? There is an opt-out via browser (do-not-track) but can we programmatically disable this behavior to prevent (arguably) sensitive information being collected when it's not relevant to the use case?

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch here:

Without knowing exactly what sort of ‘user signature’ you are referring to here, this is tough to answer. We do collect certain data about the user’s device in order power the deep linking platform, and you can read about how this is used in our [Privacy Policy](https://branch.io/policies/#privacy).  Branch of course does follow all relevant requirements from Apple and Google regarding use of private/sensitive user data, and any individual user may visit this page to opt out of all tracking and collection on the Branch platform: http://branch.app.link/optout

Comment: Thanks Alex. Let's take the IP-address. Can we disable collection of that specifically as part of app interaction with Branch libraries? As I mentioned earlier, the privacy policy only allows the user (outside the app) to opt-out, and not the app on behalf of the user.